# Jquery .data(), how to retrieve elements with matching values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that creates a new drop pin. That pin is in a div. It also created a hidden from input to record the position of that pin when it is dragged. In my creation Jquery code I stamp the div for the pin and the input with `.data("my_id",pinNumber)`. PinNumber increments when a new pin is created. This means both the div with the new pin and the input have a data key called my_id with the same value.

When a use clicked delete on a pin, I want it to remove the div and input related to the div. Here's my delete code.

```
$(".close").live("click", function() {
  var this_id = $(this).parent("div").data("my_id");
$('div[data:my_id='+this_id+']').remove();
```

the var this_id is returning the correct pin Id. However I'm running into issues on how to select elements based on data value, not data key.

How do I do this? How would I select all elements or all divs or all inputs, whatever, where data value = a  specified value? I'm talking Jquery `.data()` not HTML data- tags.

PS I'm using `live()` because these pins are created when the use hits new pin so the DOM element doesn't exist when the code first goes live. A use could created 30 pins. I need a way, and I think the `data()` method would work best, for connecting the pin div with the input created. Additionally the `.draggable()` would then report the UI location to the input with the same data value.... NEED help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and check the data value in the predicate you specify:

```
$("div, input").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("my_id") == this_id;
}).remove();
```

Comment: Remember to use the triple equals operator ===

Comment: @Greg, is there a reason why you're compelled to use the strict equality operator in this particular case?

Comment: Because you don't know what type this_id will be.  Most likely you will not run into any type coercion error here, but it is always better to use the strict equality operator to make sure both of the values being compared are of the same type.  The only case where this is not true is when you are trying to determine if a value is null or undefined.  something == null does the trick quite well

Comment: I understand your position, although I do not share it: I actually believe it's only better to use `===` instead of `==` when you actually have to use it instead of all the time. Weak typing is one of Javascript's assets, and indiscriminately going against it in all your tests in not the way to go IMHO. Now, in this particular case, I indeed do not know what type `this_id` is, but I'm pretty sure it's the same type as `data("my_id")` since that value was obtained from `data("my_id")` in the first place. Therefore, I do not think using `===` is actually necessary :)

Comment: I agree that weak typing is an asset for certain operations (such as dynamically creating a new string), but I believe that weak typing for comparing equality is one of the bad parts of the language, since it can introduce many hard to catch bugs.  I also believe that regardless of our opinions, either will work for this case :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var this_id = $(this).parent("div").data("my_id");
$('div').each(function() {
    var this = $(this);
    if(this.data("my_id") = this_id) {
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

This might work, albeit a poor example. I think the .each is bad performance wise.

Comment: The discussion with Greg Franko about equality operators made me realize you're using the assignment operator `=` in your conditional expression instead of one of the equality operators `==` or `===`. The end result will probably not be what you want.

Comment: indeed, i meant == actually, i also wouldnt have gone for the ===